# Why my Unity WebGL build does not read incoming UDP Port data?

Tags: python, c#, unity-game-engine, sockets, udp

Sorry for bothering you, i'm facing an akward issue, let me explain to you:

I'm sending data through UDP Sockets from Python to Unity, and when i start my Unity project locally (inside the app or built as an .exe) works fine. The problem is, when i build it as a WebGL Project and deploy it in local TomCat, i've  realized that the app can't read the incoming port data and it seems it's to be empty.

I don't know much about WebGL, but i probably think is something as CORS Error or maybe i'm totally confused. Would you please, help  me?

Examples:

UDP Socket (sends data from Python to Unity)

```
senderSocket.sendto(str.encode(str(object)),serverAdressPort)
```

UDP Socket (receives data in C# from Python)

```
public class UDPReceiver : MonoBehaviour {


Thread receiveThread;
UdpClient udpClient;
public int puerto = PortsEnum.PORT;
public string data;
public bool listoRecibir = true;
public bool printearConsola = false;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    receiveThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ReceivedData));
    receiveThread.IsBackground = true;
    receiveThread.Start();
}

// Update is called once per frame
private void ReceivedData()
{
    udpClient = new UdpClient(puerto);
    while (listoRecibir) {
        try
        {
            IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
            byte[] byteData = udpClient.Receive(ref ip);
            data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteData);
            if (printearConsola) { print(data); }
        }catch (Exception error){
            print(error.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

PORT is usually 7090.

Comment: Any errors or other useful information in the browser console? Might try a development build if you haven't.

Comment: Well the webgl runs on your pc not the tomcat server. Are you sure the port is open. Are you sending it to the pc? How will you know the ip of the pc and if that port is open to be accessed such as via the internet or whatever. Theres a lot of missing design info

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem with UDP and this is probably because Unity WebGL does not support UDP. You need to use WebSocket rather than UDP.